# Using DataContractResolver with AJAX-enabled wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to create a wcf service wich should be called from javascript. The service is defined as follows:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class ClientRequestService : IClientRequestService
{
    [WebGet]
    [ApplyProxyDataContractResolver]
    public ResponseData ProcessClientRequest(String pageId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This method should return an object whose type I don't know at compile time. So when it is called I get the following exception:

Type ... with data contract name ... is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I create custom DataContractResolver and create an attribute wich implements interface IOperationBehavior in order to attach my custom DataContractResolver to my service.

```
public class ApplyProxyDataContractResolverAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior =
              description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver = new ProxyDataContractResolver();
    }
}
```

The method ApplyDispatchBehavior is called successfully but methods of my custom DataContractResolver are never called and I get the same exception.

I tried to register my service either using ServiceRoute class or using svc files - it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Which documentation did you follow getting to this solution?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Anyone got an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think, is that WebHttpBehavior and WebScriptEnablingBehavior already plug in their own serialization formatter, which plugs in its own serialization operation behavior, which plugs in its own serializer. Your path never gets invoked because that custom serializer gets invoked on all serializations and deserializations.

What you need to do is override that path altogether. Here's how you do this.

If you're using WebHttpBehavior right now, subclass it. If you're using WebScriptEnablingBehavior instead, subclass that instead.

Then override these two methods:

```
System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetDefaultClientFormatter(OperationDescription, Boolean, Boolean) : IClientMessageFormatter
```

and

```
System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetDefaultDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription, Boolean, Boolean) : IDispatchMessageFormatter
```

To understand how to override them, use Reflector and take a look at their default implementations in WebHttpBehavior and WebScriptEnablingBehavior.

You'll notice that you'll have to plug in your own operation formatter, which in turn plugs in its own operation behavior, which in turn plugs in your new serializer. Take a look at the implementations of DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter and DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior and see how they are used and instantiated, to see what I mean.

I know this is more work than you probably want, but it's simpler than it sounds, and it will let you do exactly what you're looking for!